# Setting an Entry field using sum

Tags: categories, entry

I'm looking to set a 'score' property on my "category" field, this will be done by calculating how many entries are within that category similar to a 'Trending' feature.

Is there any way to set a property by doing a sum something like entry.count x 0.4 and then setting the field with the result?

Thanks

Comment: Since this value is always dynamic you could just `count` the elements each time you would like to display the number rather than save it into a field. Otherwise you would have to use the `onSave` event to store the information

Comment: @RobinSchambach That’s a solid answer, you should post it. I actually think that’s the best solution.